Cenpy 2021 ACS access?
Having trouble accessing Census 2021 5-year ACS data using the cenpy package in Python. Has anyone else run into this issue?
cxn = cen.products.ACS(2021)
variable = ["B19013_001E"]
data = cxn.query(
    cols=variable,
    g_unit="tract",
    g_filter = {'state': '41',
            'county': '101'} 
)


NotImplementedError: The requested year (2021) is too early/late. Only 2017, 2018, or 2019 are supported.

I tried using cenpy to access census 2021 5-year ACS data. I've updated the package and restarted my kernel but I still get the error.

The cenpy package has not been updated in at least 2 years. The NotImplementedError message occurs at https://github.com/cenpy-devs/cenpy/blob/master/cenpy/products.py#L682 . Possibly contact the developers requesting support for years after 2019.
